# Is every stable matrix negative definite in some scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Assume $A$ has negative eigenvalues only, but is not necessarily symmetric or even diagonalizable. Is there a positive definite symmetric matrix $M$ such that $A$ is negative definite with respect to $M$, i.e., such that
$$
\langle Ax,x\rangle_M +\langle x,Ax\rangle_{M}:= x^TA^TMx+x^{\top}MAx<-cx^TMx=:\langle x,x\rangle_M
$$
for some $c>0$ and all $x$

Background:
We have
$$
e^{At}\to0
$$
as $t\to \infty$, but the matrix norm (corresponding to the Euclidean norm) is not monotonically decaying in general. 
If the answer to the question is yes, then we do have
$$
\|e^{At}\|\leq e^{-ct}
$$
in the matrix norm corresponding to $M$.

Comment: That doesn't seems true generally, unless $A$ is symmetric: $A^T=\begin{pmatrix}-1&a\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$, $ A^TB$ is not symmetric  for $a\neq 0$ and $B>0$

Comment: @TomiMhax why would the product need to be symmetric?

Comment: ok no thought, tx

Comment: [Continuous Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation).

Comment: @user1551 yup, that's exactly what I was looking for (and looking at it made me realize that I was using the "wrong" definition of positive definiteness for my non-symmetric matrix $A$.)